# Getelementsbyname issue

Tags: vba, automation, web-search

I am having a little issue and need help.

I am trying to automate searching on website but get elements by name is not working on that specific website.
The same code is working with other websites such as bing, or google, but it is not working on my specific website that I want to use on.

I might be indexing the name location incorrect since there are many "names" in the website, however I tested one by one changing from 0 to 20, non of them worked.
I tried get elements by id but it is not working either.

Can anyone tell me what might be the reason and what can be the solution?

Do some websites restrict use of get element method, or web automation as a whole?

Comment: Maybe the content is in an iframe? Hard to know without being able to see the website.

Comment: To answer your second question, yes, some websites make great efforts to prevent you from scraping data. (like finance based sites)

Comment: -braX thank you for your response. Is there any way to check if website restricts data scraping?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. However, an experienced person would be able to look at the website to figure out which technique would work. (I am not that person) There are many ways to go about it. I do know that you cannot just pick a technique and expect it to work on all websites.

Comment: Best advice would be to look into Selenium.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.